# Flutter: CircularProgressIndicator() not working when the video is buffering

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm new to Flutter and Dart. My goal is to make a video with play, pause, replay, and buffer. My problem now is that I called the CircularProgressIndicator() but it won't work.

This is what I did:

```
final bool isBuffering = false;
```

and here is where I called the CircularProgressIndicator

```
Widget _buildPlayStack() {
    return Stack(
      children: [
        _buildPlay(),
          child: FlatButton(
            onPressed: () => setState(() {
               _vidController.value.isPlaying ? _vidController.pause() :_vidController.play();           
            }),
            child: Center(
              child: (_vidController.value.isPlaying)
                      ? Icon(Icons.pause, color: Colors.green)
                      : Icon(Icons.play_arrow, color: Colors.green),
            ),
          ),
        Center(
            child: _vidController.value.isBuffering
                ? const CircularProgressIndicator()
                : null),
      ],
    );
  }

Widget _buildPlay() {
    return Container(
      child: AspectRatio(
          aspectRatio: _vidController.value.aspectRatio,
          child: VideoPlayer(_controller),
        ),
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass in some `value:`, like:

```
child: showProgress
          ? CircularProgressIndicator(value:progress)
          : Text('Click on Refreseh button
```

And you have to update the progress using setState

For your case specifically, flutter has documentation just for you.
[Play and pause a video](https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/plugins/play-video)

Comment: Hi @CalciferHowl make sure you use the correct kind of player plugin for your video. If you are streaming from YouTube or Vimeo, there are separate flutter plugins for that.

Comment: Hi @thusith.92 I used a video from the internet. So I used VideoPlayerController.network :)

Comment: Hi! I tried passing in some values like what you gave me but the output will always show the CircularProgressIndicator nonstop. What should I do?

Answer (score 0):

This helped me.

Make a new stateful widget only for the progress bar and assign a listener to it to listen to the changes that whether the video is buffering or playing. Pass the controller object to the VideoProgressBar widget.

This separate widget(VideoProgressBar) ensures that only the progress bar is redrawn multiple times and not the whole VideoViewScreen widget.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:video_player/video_player.dart';

class VideoViewScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  final String videoURL;

  const VideoViewScreen({
    Key? key,
    required this.videoURL,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<VideoViewScreen> createState() => _VideoViewScreenState();
}

class _VideoViewScreenState extends State<VideoViewScreen> {
  late VideoPlayerController _controller;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _controller = VideoPlayerController.networkUrl(
      Uri.parse(widget.videoURL),
    )
      ..setLooping(true)
      ..initialize().then((value) {
        _controller.play(); //autoplay whenever it is initialized
      });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: blackColor,
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
          children: [
            Stack(
              alignment: Alignment.center,
              children: [
                _controller.value.isInitialized
                    ? AspectRatio(
                        aspectRatio: _controller.value.aspectRatio,
                        child: VideoPlayer(
                          _controller,
                        ),
                      )
                    : const SizedBox(
                        height: 220,
                      ),
                VideoProgressBar(controller: _controller),
                //To show that the video is buffering
              ],
            ),
            VideoProgressIndicator(
              _controller,
              allowScrubbing: true,
              colors: const VideoProgressColors(bufferedColor: colorPrimary),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _controller.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }
}


class VideoProgressBar extends StatefulWidget {
  final VideoPlayerController controller;

  const VideoProgressBar({Key? key, required this.controller})
      : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<VideoProgressBar> createState() => _VideoProgressBarState();
}

class _VideoProgressBarState extends State<VideoProgressBar> {
  var showLoadingProgress = true;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((timeStamp) {
      widget.controller.addListener(() {
        if (widget.controller.value.isBuffering) {
          if (!showLoadingProgress) {
            setState(() {
              showLoadingProgress = true;
            });
          }
        } else if (widget.controller.value.isPlaying) {
          if (showLoadingProgress) {
            setState(() {
              showLoadingProgress = false;
            });
          }
        }
      });
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      height: 40,
      width: 40,
      child: showLoadingProgress ? const CircularProgressIndicator() : const SizedBox(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).